# show limited tags in an article

Tags: php, functions, tags

I have a code that returns all the tags for the article. But that is not what I want, I only want to return the author name as the tag.

```
<?php the_tags() ?></span> <br />
```

This will return all the tags that are assigned to the article. What would i have to do so that it only returns the author name?

Default code which returns all the TAGS in a post including the author's name.

```
<?php 
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
    $user_info = get_userdata($post->the_author);
    $first = $user_info->last_name;         
    $last = $user_info->last_name;  
    wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $first, true );     
    if ( has_tag('$first-$last') ) { $author_tag = get_term_by( 'slug', '$first-$last', 'post_tag' ); 
    echo esc_html( $author_tag->name ); }       
?>
```

Comment: Are you actually setting up the author as a separate tag? WP automatically stores an author for each post, which you can access with `the_author()`.

Comment: You should use [get_the_author()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author) function.

Comment: I have author's name as tag (separate tag). It is linking to /tag/AuthorName. where would i insert the_author() in my code?

Comment: the_author would return their name but it would link to /author/AuthorName which is not what I want.

Comment: Can you somehow distinguish the author's tag from the others, e.g. after the prefix?

Comment: @nmr I don't quite understand what you meant by distinguish

Comment: Tags for authors begins with `aut-`, e.g. `aut-john`, `aut-jack`, other tags not.

Comment: This is just returning the tag/firstname-lastname when I hover over the tag

Comment: You can try [`has_tag()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_tag/) and [`get_term_by()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by): `if ( has_tag('firstname-lastname') ) { $author_tag = get_term_by( 'slug', 'firstname-lastname', 'post_tag' ); echo esc_html( $author_tag->name ); }`

Comment: @nmr where would I need to put that code?

Comment: In the place where you want to display this text, probably (but I'm just guessing) instead of `<?php the_tags() ?></span>`

Comment: it doesn't display anything. It just leaves a blank space.

Comment: If you remove `$author_tag = .... ` and add `$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'post_tag' ); foreach( $terms as $t ) { echo "<br>id= {$t->term_id}, slug= {$t->slug}, name= {$t->name}"; }`, what do you see at the author's tag?

Comment: Nothing. I've tried something different. Check it out. The code does make the author-tag, however, how would i make it so that I see first_name & last_name, the above code seperates both the first name and last name

Comment: This code adds the tag (if it does not exist yet) when the post is displayed. In my opinion, this should be done when creating a new post. Remove last line `echo the_tags()` from code you pasted, add the first code that I suggested and replace `'firstname-lastname'` with `"$first-$last"` in it. Now the tag name should be displayed, but for now without a link.

Comment: still nothing. check the updated code

Comment: `$first` and `$last` are variable names, so `'$first-$last'` is not the same as `"$first-$last"`. If you display both with `echo` you will see the difference. Use `"$first-$last"` in code.

Comment: It still doesn't display however, why does it only effect some posts? It should have effected all the posts. But only some shows it. Editing in the home.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code with changes:

```
<?php 
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
    $user_info = get_userdata($post->post_author);  // <-- or: $user_info = get_the_author_meta('ID')
    $first = $user_info->first_name;   // what if it is empty or contains forbidden characters?
    $last = $user_info->last_name;    // as obove
    wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $first, true );   // <-- tag slug, used in the code below

    // --- display tag ---
    if ( has_tag("$first") )
    {
        $author_tag = get_term_by( 'slug', "$first", 'post_tag' ); 
        if ( $author_tag instanceof WP_term )
        {
            $a_name = $author_tag->name;
            $a_link = get_term_link( $author_tag->term_id );
            // display tag
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $a_link ) . '" rel="tag">' . $a_name . '</a> ';
        }
    }

?>
```

Personally, I would move the code adding the tag to action hook [`save_post_{post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/) and execute when `$update` parameter is **FALSE** (a new post was created).

```
add_action( 'save_post_post', 'se337414_add_author_tag', 20, 3 );
function se337414_add_author_tag( $post_id, $post, $update )
{
    // create tag only when post is created
    if ( $update == true )
        return;

    $user_info = get_userdata( $post->post_author ); 
    $tag_parts = [];
    if ( !empty($user_info->first_name) )
        $tag_parts[] = $user_info->first_name;
    if ( !empty($user_info->last_name) )
        $tag_parts[] = $user_info->last_name;

    $tag_slug = implode( '-', $tag_parts );
    if ( empty($tag_slug) )
        return;

    wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $tag_slug, true );
}
```